# three minipages in a page as 2 * 1 parts

Tags: tcolorbox, minipage

I need three boxes on a page such that two of them are next to each other and the next one should be placed below one of them. I could only provide those two boxes which are next to each other. However, when I want to put the third box below one of them, it is placed on the next page. In fact, I need something like [image].

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin = 0.1 in, a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][t]{0.45\textwidth}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=box 1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[t][0.45\paperheight][t]{0.45\paperwidth}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=box 2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{minipage}[t][0.45\paperheight][t]{0.45\paperwidth}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=box  3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{minipage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


   \end{document}
```

Comment: why put `tcolorbox` in `minipage` -- you can manipulate size of `tcolorbox` directly same as in `minipage`

Comment: dear @js bibra, I just want to compile them as three colorful boxes. I have no idea what you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, % <--- in real document delete tis option
            margin = 0.1 in, a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

{
\tcbset{width=0.45\linewidth, height=0.4\linewidth,
        before=,after=\hfill}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=box 1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=box 2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=box 3]
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{document}
```